# How to sort values by a column in a pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, pivot-table

Could you please help me with sorting the values by a column in a pivot table in Python?

I've tried to sort the values in a dataframe before I created the pivot table, but, unfortunately, it didn't help me.

So, here I have the sorted data by date column and ascending=False:

[image]

Then I created a pivot table, and here is the result:

[image]

Please, help me to sort my pivot table by a date column where ascending=False.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `[]` from `index, columns, values` for remove `MultiIndex` and then sorting columns by [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df = (alert_.pivot_table(index='col1', columns='col2', values='col3')
            .sort_index(axis=1, ascending=False))
```